# Spring Security - OAuth 2.0 Client - Client Credentials Grant

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'd like to generate an access token using the Client Credentials Grant
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.6/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-client-creds-grant

We are using spring security 5.4.6

I have these dependencies imported:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

This is a resource server that also has to make a server-to-server authenticated request based on a cron schedule.  Which is why I need to the `resource-server` and `oauth2-client` dependencies.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://auth.pingone.com/...
      client:
        provider:
          pingidentity:
            token-uri: https://auth.pingone.com/.../as/token
        registration:
          pingidentity:
            client-id: "69bxxxxx..."
            client-secret: "Xxxxx"
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: "client_credentials"
```

```
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository ) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .clientCredentials()
                        .build();

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository );
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider( authorizedClientProvider );

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    protected void setSecurityContext() {
        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId( "pingidentity" )
                .principal( "69bbfc70-8fcf-4740-a11a-b86562d1c9f8" )
//              .attributes( attrs -> {
//                  attrs.put( HttpServletRequest.class.getName(), servletRequest );
//                  attrs.put( HttpServletResponse.class.getName(), servletResponse );
//              } )
                .build();
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.authorizedClientManager.authorize( authorizeRequest );

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();
}
```

I'm getting this error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: servletRequest cannot be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.authorize(DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.java:144)
at com.edlogics.heathrow.api.scheduling.jobs.AbstractSchedulerJob.setSecurityContext(AbstractSchedulerJob.java:42)
at com.edlogics.heathrow.api.scheduling.jobs.CheckForMissingCacheEntriesJob.execute(CheckForMissingCacheEntriesJob.java:32)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)

How can I can use the client credentials grant outside of a web request?

Comment: Have you considered using a WebClient with an ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction , this way it will do everything for you, source the access token, and even get a new one if it expires.

Comment: @WojciechLesniak thank you. I found an example of that and it looks like it might work for me. Do you know if there is a way to update the security context of the client that is initiating the call?

Comment: Can you provide more info for this usecase, how do you want to update the security context?

Comment: @WojciechLesniak I appreciate your help. I tried to go down the path of WebClient with an ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction. In order to do that you have to bring all the webflux and reactive stuff into your project and spring boot wants to auto-configure that instead.  I ended up figuring out that my problem was that I was using DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager instead of AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager. The latter is used for services that do not have web requests (server-to-server).